# Module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'norm'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scipy, anaconda

I have a very simple minimal example:

```
import scipy.stats

CRV = scipy.stats.norm
```

That code gives me an error in my Jupyter Notebook:

`AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'norm'`

I tried multiple things: reinstalling scipy, then reinstalling anaconda, and this keeps happening. I am not sure what could go wrong, my Scipy was on 1.11.1.

EDIT:

I ran the following code:

```
print(scipy.__path__)
print(scipy.stats.__path__)
```

And got the following results:

```
_NamespacePath(['C:\\Users\\user1\\anaconda3\\envs\\project\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy'])
_NamespacePath(['C:\\Users\\user1\\anaconda3\\envs\\project\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\stats'])
```

Comment: What does `print(scipy.stats)` show?

Comment: @Brian61354270 it says `<module 'scipy.stats' (<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x000001E1B2AAB880>)>`

Comment: That means that `scipy.stats` is a namespace package. The _actual_ [`scipy.stats` module from scipy v1.11.1](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/v1.11.1/scipy/stats) is not a namespace package. Do you have a directory named `scipy` somewhere on your import path? What does `print(scipy.stats.__path__)` and `print(scipy.__path__)` show?

Comment: @Brian61354270 print(scipy) shows `<module 'scipy' (<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x000001E1B4CE6BF0>)>`. I am not entirely sure how and where to check the import path, but the curious thing is that I tried changin environments (which should each have their own imports, no?) and it still did not work.

Comment: I edited the command after posting my comment. Can you show the output of the modified prints? Also, please add the output of those prints to the question with an [edit].

Comment: @Brian61354270 Thank you, I updated my question with the info you requested.

Comment: If you browse to those paths in a file explorer, what do you see? Do you see `__init__.py` files in both directories? Or are there only `.pyc` files, or do there appear to be files missing?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you installed scipy?

Comment: @Brian61354270 yes, in both of these, I see a non empty  `__init.__.py` file that looks to be correct inside. I installed scipy using DataSpell's native "python packages" tool that allowed me to directly install the package.

Comment: Strange. I'm not sure why Python is treating them as namespace packages if there are `__init__.py` files present. Can you confirm that `dir(scipy.stats)` is mostly empty (only a handful of `__dunder__` entries)? If the `__init__.py` was processed (for non-namespace packages),  we would expect it to contain a few hundred entries.

Comment: Are you able to explicitly import `scipy.stats._continuous_distns`? That's the submodule that `norm` comes from.

Comment: @Brian61354270 the `dir(scipy.stats)` is not empty, it contains a great number of entries, INCLUDING `norm`. Yet when I run it, it still says the package does not exist. I was able to import `scipy.stats._continuous_distns` yet when I use the norm function, which should be (and actually is) there, it says the function does not exist.

Comment: Now that's perplexing. So `dir(scipy.stats)` contains `norm`, but `scipy.stats.norm` raises an attribute error? Just to confirm, are both those statements being run in the same place? Is there a longer traceback for the `AttributeError`? If so, can you add it to the question?

Comment: @Brian61354270 It works now - I haven't changed anything, but after several tries, it just suddenly started to accept the `norm` function. No idea what happened. Sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: Glad its working now! Did it start working when you restarted the Jupyter kernel? Maybe some of the symptoms we were seeing were due to the scipy installation changing while an old kernel was still running.

Comment: @Brian61354270 It did start working after a kernel restart - however, I restarted the kernel multiple times, only the last one was successful in solving the issue (and I hope it will remain solved). Once again, thank you!